# oraops.dll not found in 64 bit os and 32 bit process of vs 2008

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

Hi Can any one tell me how to resolve the issue of OraOps10.dll not found , I am using oracle 11g and VS 2008 (32 bit process) and 64 bit OS(Win 7). Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

Find the .dll and add it directly to your project (not as a reference) as "Add Existing Item."  Once a part of your project, make sure you change the "Copy to output directory" property to true.

I think the easier way, however is to install the package, which in VS 2013 you do through the tools->Package Manager, which will do the same thing.  This is better because I think it installs both the 32 and 64 bit versions, so it works on either platform when you go to deploy the solution.  I don't recall if the package manager was available prior to VS 2010.